# Every time fetched Lazy OneToMany collection

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many

I have a Patient who has a Set of NeurologicalFinding medical records.

Patient class structure is as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "patient")
public class PatientEntity {

   //other properties

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "patient")
   private Set<NeurologicalFindingEntity> neurologicalFindingList;

   public Set<NeurologicalFindingEntity> getNeurologicalFindingList() {        
    return neurologicalFindingList; //DEBUGGER never got to this line
   }

   //other get and set methods
}
```

NeurologicalFinding class structure is as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "neurological_finding")
public class NeurologicalFindingEntity{

   //other properties

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "patient_id")
   private PatientEntity patient;

   //get and set methods
}
```

In my app, I want to get a Patient by his ID without his NeurologicalFinding records with the following method of the DAO:

```
public PatientEntity getPatientById(int patientId) {      

   Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createCriteria(PatientEntity.class);

   criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", patientId));

   return (PatientEntity) criteria.uniqueResult();
}
```

When I use this method I still get patient WITH his NeurologicalFinding records.
The getter of the collection is never called (checked with debuger), so how is it possible that the lazy collection is loaded when nobody asked for it?

If you need more info about my app I can provide you with it.

Comment: Hey, I'm interested to know which line of code did you watch using your debugger? Can u add a unit of your code where it calls getPatientById()?

Comment: Also, why not use `Session.get()` instead of this Criteria query? It would be more efficient, and simpler. To answer your question, my guess is that what calls the getter and loads the list is your debugger. Create a unit test and use `Hibernate.isInitialized(patient.getNeurologicalFindingList())` to check if the list is really loaded. Or simply look at the SQL queries being generated in this test.

Comment: @CodeBender I added the getter of the property "neurologicalFindingList" into the code.

Comment: @JB Nizet The debuger is a really nice guess, I will check it out. Also thanks for the given advice.

Comment: @JB Nizet As for the debuger, the PatientEntity also has a OneToOne Contact which is EAGER but when I make it lazy and WONT spacify "criteria.setFetchMode("contact", FetchMode.JOIN);" in my criteria, it is not loaded and debuger shows me contacts properties as null and there is a JavassistLazyInitializer waiting. Then, when I call getContact() it is inicialized, so I don't think that it is a debugger related thing. It happens only on ManyToMany and OneToMany associations (oposite side ManyToOne works fine - null properties and waiting inicializer).

Comment: Any code unit in your service layer that calls getPatientById? I just did a project and was in the same scenario as yours, my lazy fetch works fine. My suspect is the same as JB Bizet: accidentally lazy fetched your list while debugBing. The moment you check for the list size, it could have triggered.

Comment: @CodeBender I know what you guys are saying with the debuger, but it didn't inicialize other collections which I accessed via debuger, so I guess that this is not the gist of the problem.

Comment: It was indeed the debuger. Thank you guys a lot. I am still wondering why the debuger inicializes the OneToMany List but not ManyToOne single property. I was accessing both of them from both sides of the relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `hibernate.show_sql = true` to print the queries and confirm if lazy loading is working or not:

```
   <bean id= "entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" >
         ...
         <property name="jpaProperties" >
               <props>
                     ...
                     <prop key="hibernate.show_sql" >true</ prop>
                     <prop key="hibernate.format_sql" >true</ prop>
                     <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
          ...
```

`use_sql_comments` is especially important, as it will print a comment at the beginning of the query stating the reason why the query is written: one-to-many, named query name, criteria query text, etc.

Then by putting breakpoints it's possible to see if the collection is fetched at the moment you inspect it with the debugger.

If it's not the case, and the getter is not called, then it could be that the lazy loading is being triggered directly inside the class via direct access to the property `neurologicalFindingList`.

Are you accessing the property directly inside `PatientEntity`, for example in equals and hashcode? If so by removing it from the equals and hashcode the problem should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for nice props, they are really helpful. I had show_sql turned on but it was not readable without format_sql.
Finally, I have found out that it is really debuger who fetches a OneToMany List. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For one, you could use `EntityManager.find()` instead of a criteria query in this particular scenario. Secondly, you could try putting the annotation on the setter instead of the field. Thirdly, you can also specify `fetch=LAZY` on the other side of the relationship, but I don't think that's what you need.

Finally, what I found in my experience (although this applied to EclipseLink, not necessarily Hibernate) is that in order to support lazy fetching, sometimes bytecode weaving is required. Each JPA provider usually has a tool for that (along with an Ant task and a Maven plugin).